# On user closing bb10(z10) app , its taking long time to access app icon on home screen

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, blackberry-10, blackberry-qnx

The scenario is my app is using web view(java script for map) , on user closing the app he has to wait for some time(the icon image is blurred on home screen signifying app is not ready). Does bb10 O.S handle closing of object instance or it should be handled at app side. From my knowledge all the object instance are closed on exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug on the BB10 issue tracker about this - https://www.blackberry.com/jira/browse/BBTEN-612. It looks like this is still present, unless you're using an old sdk?

Comment: we are using latest bb10 SDK

Comment: I'd suggest reopening the issue then